# Hidden input value is empty on javascript form's submission code

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

I have the following form using AlpineJS:

```
<form x-data="inquiry()" x-on:submit.prevent="submit" method="post">
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" x-model="data.email">
  <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="my subject" x-model="data.subject">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

And the submission javascript code is:

```
<script>
  function inquiry() {
    return {
      data: {
        email: "",
        subject: ""
      },
      submit() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data));
      }
    };
  }
```

When filling the form's email and submitting it I get the email's value in the console.

However the subject value from the hidden input is always empty.

What am I missing?

Comment: Aren't you emptying it yourself here? `subject: ""` Probably should be `subject: "my subject"` and the `value` attribute removed.

Answer (score 1):

Well this worked for me,
I believe you can't set the x-model by filling value, you just need to set it in the x-model

```
x-model="data.subject = 'my subject'"
```

Comment: It works but I get the error on the console "Alpine Expression Error: Left side of assignment is not a reference." on the code line `x-model="data.subject = 'my subject'"`. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You can set **subject** inside **inquiry()** and keep **x-model** like this `x-model="data.subject"` that will work